# What would cause Firefox to request a resource multiple times after executing an external script?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm noticing some unusual behavior in Firefox when I include an image directly after a call to an external script.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src='external.js'></script>
<img src="/test.gif" BORDER=0 WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 >

</body>
</html>
```

"external.js" can be anything at all...even completely blank.

I notice that when a request to test.gif results in a 404 or 302, Firefox makes another request for that same resource immediately after the script has completed.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2011:16:22:22 -0400] "GET /test.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 507 
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2011:16:22:22 -0400] "GET /test.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 507
```

This behavior doesn't occur for inline javascript, and I have pipelining turned off, so I'm fairly certain it's not related to that.  Seems like odd behavior, or I'm just missing something not-so-obvious.

I'm using Firefox 3.16 on Ubuntu, but this was also verified with Firefox 4.0 on OSX and Firefox 3.16 on Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should probably report this at bugzilla.mozilla.org.  It smells like a bug in the HTTP resource prefetcher to me.

Comment: And you need nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred and ninety nine iterations for...?

Comment: @Shaz I think he was just duplicating the nature of a long running JS process

Comment: @Shaz The purpose of that was merely to stall the script.  On further investigation, though, the behavior still occurs even when completely blank.   I'll taking that out to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to image prefetch (or more precisely the image cache) in Firefox not dealing well with non-2xx return codes.

In particular, for 302 the issue is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552605 and for 404 the issue is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648568